# Error while installing Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, windows-xp, cygwin

I am trying to learn hadoop and I am following the installation steps on http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/12%20-%20format%20the%20namendoe.html. However I am getting the following error and I have no clues why is it not able to find PlatformName in the classpath. Also I am concerned about,"cygpath: can't convert empty path". Can anyone let me know what might be the reason that I am getting this error.

Thank you

```
V6X5932@MC1BCCNU2320D09 ~/hadoop-0.22.0
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
cygpath: can't convert empty path
cygpath: can't convert empty path
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
cygpath: can't convert empty path
cygpath: can't convert empty path
12/10/17 15:49:03 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = MC1BCCNU2320D09/40.9.146.66
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.22.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = C:\cygwin\home\V6X5932\hadoop-                                   
Re-format filesystem in \tmp\hadoop-V6X5932\dfs\name ? (Y or N) N
Format aborted in \tmp\hadoop-V6X5932\dfs\name
12/10/17 15:52:10 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at MC1BCCNU2320D09/40.9.146.66
************************************************************/
```

Comment: Run it in verbose mode to see what `cygpath` is complaining about. Run it without parameters snd it might tell you the switches. If not open the script and put `set -xv` at the top or run it under `bashdb`

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Cloudera VM](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Downloads) for Hadoop Cluster setup. It's a ready made setup so that one can spend time in learning Hadoop rather than setting up it's prerequisites. I wanted to learn Apache Hive when I faced similar situations and I had to switch to Cloudera VM.

Comment: I have a 32 bit windows XP OS on my workstation. I checked the Cloudera site if I can find a VM for 32 bit host OS and seems like they do not have it. Do I have any other option ?

Comment: People have already asked for 32 bit support on forums but no response. Take a look at http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/07/cloudera-training-vm-virtualbox/ and https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cdh-user/Vrxnj_RzoV8

Comment: Thank you for that. I am installing virtual box on my XP now.

Comment: I tried installing cloudera and ran into some issue. I installed ubuntu on my pc and successfully installed hadoop on it, without any issues. I followed the tutorial here http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Comment: thanks for sharing...its a great help in the sense that one doesn't have to download n install Cloudera VM and suffer from 64 bit issues!!